# UTF-8 Data is getting lost while using Methodinfo.invoke method to call c# method from c++

Tags: c#, c++, utf-8

I am calling dotNET class from C++ program using methodinfo.invoke method.Parameter for the invoke method is a string.The value of the string is in UTF-8 codepage.while printing the parameter via dotnet method it is printing ASCII charater. Data is getting lost.

c++ program:

```
MethodInfo *mi = NULL;
char *param="Şəçüöğ";
String *args[] = new String*[1]; 
 args[0]= new String(param);  
printf("from try %s",args[0]);
String *str=static_cast<String*>(mi->Invoke(o,args));
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace T24Unicode
{
    public class UnicodeTest
    {
        public string GetData(string text1)
        {

         byte[] utf = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text1);
         string s2= System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf);
          Console.WriteLine("The value returned from .cs when writing the parameter using Console.WriteLine : "+s2);
          return text1;
         }
     }
}
output:
```

The value returned from .cs when writing the parameter using Console.WriteLine:

> ÅžÉ™Ã§Ã¼Ã¶ÄŸ

can someone please help on this?

Comment: "[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)"

Comment: You may be using the wrong font to display the data.  The Console has a default font which is not the same as the data you are displaying.  You can change the console font.

Comment: `byte[] utf = ...; ... .GetString(utf);` converts an UTF-16 encoded string to an UTF-8 byte array and back to a UTF-16 encoded string. So it doesn't really do anything. Your problem is more likely with the encoding of the C++ source file, the encoding used by the C++ compiler, the encoding used by `printf`, the encoding used by `Console.WriteLine` or the encoding of your console window. Use the debugger to inspect your string variables instead.